# Discord Python: Accepting two inputs separated by a comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to make a python bot for Discord, a free voice call and chat application. I'm working on a command that accepts two inputs. I've gotten it working, but only if the two inputs are one word long each. If I wanted each input to be longer than one world, I'd have to put it in quotes.

[Chat] /dist sol eravate
[Chat] 75ly

But if I did

[Chat] /dist LHS 3447 sol
[Chat] ...

The command would not work because the bot thinks "LHS" and "3447" are the two inputs, when it is in fact "LHS 3447" as one input and "sol" as the second input. But it works if I put the two input in quotes:

[chat] /dist "LHS 3447" "sol"
[chat] 7ly

This is the code that produced those results:

```
async def dist(sys1,sys2):
    sys1plus = sys1.replace(" ", "+")
    sys2plus = sys2.replace(" ", "+")
    base1 = 'http://www.edsm.net/api-v1/system?sysname=' + sys1plus + '&coords=1'
    base2 = 'http://www.edsm.net/api-v1/system?sysname=' + sys2plus + '&coords=1'
    ...
```

I've also tried:

```
async def dist(sys):
    sys1, sys2 = sys.split(",")
    sys1plus = sys1.replace(" ", "+")
    sys2plus = sys2.replace(" ", "+")
    base1 = 'http://www.edsm.net/api-v1/system?sysname=' + sys1plus + '&coords=1'
    base2 = 'http://www.edsm.net/api-v1/system?sysname=' + sys2plus + '&coords=1'
    ...
```

But it'd still separate the two arguments at the space when the inputs are longer than one word.

[Chat] /dist sol,eravate
[Chat] 7ly
[Chat] /dist sol,45 Tauri
[Chat] ...

**How would I make it so that the two inputs can include spaces, using a comma to split them?** I understand this may be a problem with the Discord API wrapper, but I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have a way of getting all inputted arguments as a single string?

Answer (score 0):

if you have spaces in your command line input, you must wrap it with quotes.
otherwise, the command line thinks you are giving a second or third argument (arguments are separated by spaces)

I recommend using one argument with quotes:

```
/dist "sol,other thing with spaces"
```

and

```
async def dist(sys):
    sys1, sys2 = sys.split(",")
    # sys1 = "sol", sys2 = "other thing with spaces"
    # continue code
```